# HTML5 Canvas lineTo() colour per line

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have a line with two points, it goes up then it goes down. What I'm looking to do is change the colour when rendering the next part of the line. E.g lineTo in red, then lineTo in blue.

This is the example I've been working with in fiddle, the comments explain what I've tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/5utenwz3/9/

It seems when I change the colour in line 16, it overrides the colour of the first part too (line 10). Is it possible in canvas to colour the next segment independently of the previous?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();

context.moveTo(100, 150);

// set line color for first part (red)
context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
context.lineTo(250, 50);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.stroke();

// set line color for next part (blue)
context.strokeStyle = '#063C75';
context.lineTo(450, 90);
context.stroke();

// expectation: first part (upward) line is red. second part (downward) is blue
// reality: whole line is blue
```

Comment: Yes, in a way - confirms a solution I've got now too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.moveTo(100, 150);
// set line color for first part (red)

context.lineTo(250, 50);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
context.stroke();

// set line color for next part (blue)
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(250, 50);
context.lineTo(450, 90);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#063C75';
context.stroke();
```